# Reuters OpenDACS .Net Framework

Tags: .net, reuters

#### Scenario

As some of you may have heard, OpenDACS is an open source data-access control system for enforcing data usage permissions. DACS comes integrated with the Reuters platform but you can use OpenDACS for extending third-party software.

#### I'm using IE6, I can't embed these links properly.

http://thomsonreuters.com/products_services/financial/financial_products/real-time/data_access_control_system

https://customers.reuters.com/developer/Kits/OpenDACS/opendacs.aspx

#### Question

Has anyone used OpenDACS at all? I'm quite interested in it but I have no idea where to start. Ideally some examples would be fantastic, or a startup guide.

#### Thoughts

I use C# heavily and am looking to extend a C# application with DACS. I understand that there is currently no C# API, however I've heard that the SFC-COM Edition can used with the .Net/COM interoperability layer

Help greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: I'm curious... Why do you use IE6?

Comment: I have limited experience with OpenDACS. There are some examples included with the software package but they're using RFA API instead of SFC. If you have a Customer Zone account, RMDS Forum is also a great place to ask .. https://infoblog.reuters.com/a/forums/rmdsforums/default.aspx

Comment: IE6 - Big Corporate Firm, typical setup I'm afraid.